# How to extract following xml using PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<person>
  <id>rfBRFK4d1s</id>
  <first-name>Thamaraiselvam</first-name>
  <last-name>T</last-name>
  <headline>Software Development Intern at Snowman Branding Services Pvt. Ltd</headline>
  <picture-url>https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_C-W9UUXaoLCdgSJ2CvJLUJ-mokL4xHd28KgWU4GxzTAd8uOuaqMVzZnlXo56pfHh_AwHNxp2yCIc</picture-url>
  <industry>Computer Software</industry>
  <educations total="2">
    <education>
      <school-name>Knowledge Institute of Technology</school-name>
      <field-of-study>Computer Science and Engineering</field-of-study>
      <start-date>
        <year>2011</year>
      </start-date>
      <end-date>
        <year>2015</year>
      </end-date>
      <degree>B.E</degree>
    </education>
    <education>
      <school-name>Knowledge institute of technology</school-name>
      <field-of-study>Computer Engineering</field-of-study>
      <start-date>
        <year>2011</year>
      </start-date>
      <end-date>
        <year>2015</year>
      </end-date>
      <degree>Bachelor of Engineering (BE)</degree>
    </education>
  </educations>
</person>
```

I'm trying to extract above xml using PHP and i tried with following code

```
$xml_response="my xml contents";
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_response);
echo $xml->person[0]['headers'] . "<br>";
echo $xml->id;
```

I can get `id` but i cannot get other things and

```
echo $xml->first-name;
```

it shows error because of that `-` between `first` and `name` then i have so many category like person details how do i create loop for that to retrieve?

Comment: Provide correct XML. This seems to be incomplete.

Comment: I have edited @PiotrOlaszewski

Comment: XML is still invalid. E.g no end tag for `<connections>`.

Comment: see now i have changed my whole file here `education` over `connections`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To correct traversing on parsed XML you must treat it as object. So a few examples:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
echo $xml->id . PHP_EOL;
echo $xml->educations->education[0]->{'school-name'} . PHP_EOL;
echo $xml->educations->education[0]->{'end-date'}->year . PHP_EOL;
```

**Note:**

Tags as `<something-with-something>` must be correctly handled by `{'something-with-something'}` expression.

---

If you want iterate nodes (here `education`):

```
foreach($xml->educations->education as $item) {
    echo $item->{'school-name'} . PHP_EOL;
    echo $item->degree . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much dear , it works fine . i have many education fields , i need to make loop here . so how do i find the size of `education` array  here my size is `2` because i have only 2 education list here

Comment: Instead of using loop use iterator - `foreach`.

Comment: Can you please tell  me `foreach` key ,variable and value? i have tried like this `foreach ($xml->educations => $value) {
echo    $value->education->{'end-date'}->year;
    # code...
}
` shows error